# How can I use JSESSIONID (session cookie) for authentication in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, liferay

So, I'm fetching data from an API that is built in Liferay (json web service) and in which I'm to integrate into a React frontend. Right now I'm at the stage where I need to authenticate a user, and I'm halfway there. I'm currently sending a post-request with the Fetch API, to a specific endpoint that is defined in the backend. From there I get back some user data in JSON format, but also a JSESSIONID cookie. I'm mostly used to using json web tokens for authentication and basically what I need to know how to use this session cookie in a similar way.

I'm thinking in my mind I want to store the cookie in a state/context, and let the application determine if there is a session, and only then be able to access protected routes, etc, but I'm not entirely sure this is the way you do it.

I would really be glad if someone could point me in the right direction.